# Print a Complex Diamond Pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to build a diamond pattern of diamond pattern. Let me break it down for you.
Currently I have a function that prints a diamond pattern with input as size.

```
def diamond(n,space=' '): 

    for i in range(n):
        print(space*(n-1-i) + "* "*(i+1))            
    for l in range(n-1,0,-1):   
        print(space*(n-l) + "* "*(l))

diamond(2)
```

My output will be a diamond of size 2

```
 * 
* * 
 *
```

Now what i really want is replace each star with this diamond pattern itself.
Desired output to look like.

[image]

Should be able to do this for all sizes, where each star of that pattern is replaced by the whole pattern.

Thank you.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548099/printing-simple-diamond-pattern-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You cannot go to a previous line once your cursor has advanced. Instead you can approach the problem differently. If you have a set of words you want to print such as

```
words = ['Hello', 'World']
```

You can print each of them `n` times as follows:

```
for word in words:
    print(word * n)
```

For `n = 2`, this gives

```
HelloHello
WorldWorld
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use np.array as a grid and put '*' with position [i][j]. In this code, empty array is made, then  check the position of * and finally set outer diamond position. There might be better code but this still works.

```
import numpy as np

n = 2

k = (2*n - 1)

# make empty array, set
# a is used for single diamond. Not necessary.
a = np.array([[' ']*k for t in range(k)])
# set of * position in array
b = set()
c = np.array([[' ']*k**2 for t in range(k**2)])

# check positions in array of single diamond 
for i in range(n**2):
    for i in range(n):
        i_reverce = k - i -1
        for j in range(i+1):
            y = n-i-1+2*j
            a[i][y] = '*'
            a[i_reverce][y] = '*'
            b.add((i,y))
            b.add((i_reverce,y))

# print(a) # use if you want to check a

positions = list(b)

# positions of * in diamond of diamond
for pos1 in positions:
    for pos2 in positions:
        x = pos1[0] * k + pos2[0]
        y = pos1[1] * k + pos2[1]
        c[x][y] = '*'

for row in c:
    print(''.join(row))
```

For n=2

```
    *    
   * *   
    *    
 *     * 
* *   * *
 *     * 
    *    
   * *   
    *
```

For n=3

```
            *            
           * *           
          * * *          
           * *           
            *            
       *         *       
      * *       * *      
     * * *     * * *     
      * *       * *      
       *         *       
  *         *         *  
 * *       * *       * * 
* * *     * * *     * * *
 * *       * *       * * 
  *         *         *  
       *         *       
      * *       * *      
     * * *     * * *     
      * *       * *      
       *         *       
            *            
           * *           
          * * *          
           * *           
            *
```

Answer (score 1):

With this recursive function you can print a complex diamond on any position of the screen.

```
import sys

def draw_diamond(x, y, diamond_size):
    # x and y represent the upper-left corner of the diamond to be drawn
    # diamond_size must be a power of 3
    if diamond_size == 1:
        sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (x, y, "*"))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        return
    subdiamond_size = diamond_size / 3
    draw_diamond(x + subdiamond_size, y, subdiamond_size)
    draw_diamond(x, y + subdiamond_size, subdiamond_size)
    draw_diamond(x + 2*subdiamond_size, y + subdiamond_size, subdiamond_size)
    draw_diamond(x + subdiamond_size, y + 2*subdiamond_size, subdiamond_size)
```

For example, `draw_diamond(5, 100, 27)` prints a diamond with dimension 27 whose upper-left corner is 5 characters from the top of the terminal and 100 characters from the left of the terminal:

```
             *
            * *
             *
          *     *
         * *   * *
          *     *
             *
            * *
             *
    *                 *
   * *               * *
    *                 *
 *     *           *     *
* *   * *         * *   * *
 *     *           *     *
    *                 *
   * *               * *
    *                 *
             *
            * *
             *
          *     *
         * *   * *
          *     *
             *
            * *
             *
```

You can get your desired output by using `diamond_size=9`. Possible sizes are 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, etc.

Your desired output can be obtained with `diamond_size=3**2`:

```
    *
   * *
    *
 *     *
* *   * *
 *     *
    *
   * *
    *
```

Comment: Sorry it should be able to print for any size of diamond

Comment: @Bane It is able to print any size!!! `diamond_size` must be 3^dimension, where dimension can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... Any number! You did not understand what I've done. And probably you did not even execute my code, which *does* compute the answer you are looking for!!

Comment: I have edited the question, my question is to replace the star in each diamond with the pattern itself, you just went one more step ahead. thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bane You can use `diamond_size=3**1` for a simple diamond, and `diamond_size=3**2` for the complex one. If you want you can build any diamond, using 27, 81, etc. Please remove the downvote and accept the answer if you like it

Answer (score 1):

Take them in strings:

```
>>> s1, s2 = '', ''
>>> for i in range(2):
...     s1 += 'Hello'
...     s2 += 'World'
... 
>>> print(s1); print(s2)
HelloHello
WorldWorld
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want all in one line, you can try:

```
>>> print(*(l*2 for l in ['Hello','World']),sep='\n')

HelloHello
WorldWorld
```

If you want to keep using range:

```
print(*(''.join((['Hello','World']*2)[i::2]) for i in range(2)), sep='\n')
```

For your second requirement, without changing your code much:

```
n=2
for i in range(n):
    s = ' '*(n-1-i) + "* "*(i+1);print(s+' '*(n-1-i)+s)
for l in range(n-1,0,-1):   
    s = ' '*(n-l) + "* "*(l);print(s+' '*(n-l)+s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think convert basic star sign to a retangle shaped string like this

```py
basic = ''' * 
* *
 * '''
print(basic)
>>> * 
>>>* *
>>> *

tolist = basic.split('\n')
x = len(tolist[0])
y = len(tolist)
'''This x, y might be the arguments you need
 to write a generator function base on size'''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the pattern to repeat, modify the str_ variable.

```
str_ = " * \n* *\n * "
str_splited = str_.split("\n")

for i in str_splited:
    for j in range(0, 3):
        print(i*j, end="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of putting one one diamond at each star(*) of the single diamond to create the full pattern. You could do it but you will have to recompute the spacing between them. My solution is based on your idea.

What I did is created a function that creates a single diamond but accepts two additional parameters X_Offset and Y_Offset. Once the star was created, all I had to do is compute the X_Offset and Y_Offset for each of the possible star and pass the previous function to this zipped list of X_Offset and Y_Offset. Finally I created a reporter function that prints the star.

This program has a lot of room for improvement since it is slow and based on for loop. Some math experts could make it fast. I am not sure if this is what you wanted. Nevertheless here it is.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=100)


def MakeADiamond(n, X_Offset, Y_Offset, Array):
    NumDrawn = 0
    StartPos_Y, StartPos_X = Y_Offset, X_Offset

    while(NumDrawn < n):
        ## Move to left edge of the diamond and start filling digonally upwards.
        ## Then move down and repeat the process until bottom of the star is reached
        for x in range(n):
            Array[StartPos_Y - x + (n-1), StartPos_X + x -n +1] = 1
        StartPos_Y += 1
        StartPos_X += 1
        NumDrawn += 1        
    return Array


def PrintFullPattern(Array):
    ## replace 1 with '*' and 0 with ' '
    ## Needed for final printing
    NewArray = np.where(Array==1, "*"," ")
    for i in NewArray:
        for j in i:
            print(j,sep="",end="")
        print()


def MakeADiamondOfDiamonds(n):
    Array = np.zeros(shape=((2*n-1)**2,(2*n-1)**2)) ## I create a placeholder for the numbers/stars
    NumDiamonds = [x for x in range(1,n,1)]+[n]+[y for y in range(n-1,0,-1)] ## Calculate the number of diamonds in each layer
    X_Offset_List = [] ## Create an empty X_Offset
    Y_Offset_List = [] ## Create an empty Y_Offset
    Y_Offset_Start = 0 ## Y_Offset for the first star must be zero  
    for eachNumDiamonds in NumDiamonds:
        X_Offset_Start = math.floor(((2*n-1)**2)/2) - (eachNumDiamonds-1) * (2*n -1)  ## Calculate the starting X_Offset for every layer                  
        for eachDiamond in range(eachNumDiamonds): ## Process each diamond of a particular layer
            X_Offset_List.append(X_Offset_Start) ## Add to X_Offset
            Y_Offset_List.append(Y_Offset_Start) ## Add to Y_Offset
            X_Offset_Start += 2*(2*n -1) ## Increment X_Offset for the next star in the same layer
        Y_Offset_Start += (2*n -1) ## Increment Y_Offset for the star in the next layer
    Offset_List = list(zip(X_Offset_List, Y_Offset_List)) ## Bring together X_Offset and Y_Offset so that they could be passed to the function

    for (eachOffset_X, eachOffset_Y) in Offset_List: ## For every X and Y offset for stars, compute a single diamond position
        Array = MakeADiamond(n, eachOffset_X, eachOffset_Y, Array)

    PrintFullPattern(Array)

MakeADiamondOfDiamonds(2)
MakeADiamondOfDiamonds(3)
MakeADiamondOfDiamonds(4)
```

The outputs respectively for 2, 3 and 4 stars are as below.

```py
    *    
   * *   
    *    
 *     * 
* *   * *
 *     * 
    *    
   * *   
    *
```

```py
            *            
           * *           
          * * *          
           * *           
            *            
       *         *       
      * *       * *      
     * * *     * * *     
      * *       * *      
       *         *       
  *         *         *  
 * *       * *       * * 
* * *     * * *     * * *
 * *       * *       * * 
  *         *         *  
       *         *       
      * *       * *      
     * * *     * * *     
      * *       * *      
       *         *       
            *            
           * *           
          * * *          
           * *           
            *
```

```py
                        *                        
                       * *                       
                      * * *                      
                     * * * *                     
                      * * *                      
                       * *                       
                        *                        
                 *             *                 
                * *           * *                
               * * *         * * *               
              * * * *       * * * *              
               * * *         * * *               
                * *           * *                
                 *             *                 
          *             *             *          
         * *           * *           * *         
        * * *         * * *         * * *        
       * * * *       * * * *       * * * *       
        * * *         * * *         * * *        
         * *           * *           * *         
          *             *             *          
   *             *             *             *   
  * *           * *           * *           * *  
 * * *         * * *         * * *         * * * 
* * * *       * * * *       * * * *       * * * *
 * * *         * * *         * * *         * * * 
  * *           * *           * *           * *  
   *             *             *             *   
          *             *             *          
         * *           * *           * *         
        * * *         * * *         * * *        
       * * * *       * * * *       * * * *       
        * * *         * * *         * * *        
         * *           * *           * *         
          *             *             *          
                 *             *                 
                * *           * *                
               * * *         * * *               
              * * * *       * * * *              
               * * *         * * *               
                * *           * *                
                 *             *                 
                        *                        
                       * *                       
                      * * *                      
                     * * * *                     
                      * * *                      
                       * *                       
                        *
```

Hope this helps.