# print a diamond in python

Tags: python

I have tried so many times now to make a diamond, but I can't manage to get the Reverse Pyramid Shape right. I have the upper part of the diamond right I think.

```py
#The upper part
N=input()
for a in range(N):
        print(" "*(N-a)+"X"*(2*a+1))
```

Can someone please help me with the second part of the diamond?

Comment: Is there any symmetry in a diamond that you can take advantage of? If so, how can your code reflect that symmetry?

Comment: replace `N=input()` with `N=int(input())` , it throws an error at the next lines.

Comment: You can use `reversed()` to count backwards instead of forwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Simple Diamond Pattern in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548099/printing-simple-diamond-pattern-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for a in range(N):
     print(" "*a+"X"*(2*(N-a)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

whole code

```py
N=int(input(""))
for a in range(N):
    print(" "*(N-a)+"X"*(2*a+1))

for a in range(N,-1, -1):
    print(" "*(N-a)+"X"*(2*a+1))
```