# Trying to make this diamond shape using for loops:

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I am trying to make a diamond shape using loops in python. This is my code so far:

```
facesize=10
radius=5

for line in range(facesize):
    rightshift= ""
    for shift in range(5):
        rightshift= " "
        print(rightshift)
    print("-")
```

Please help on how I can fix this. I am trying to make something like this:

```
            -
          -   -
        -       -
      -           -
    -               -  
      -           -
        -       -
          -   -
            -
```

Comment: Please add a language tag to the question.

Comment: Just added it. I am using python.

Comment: But the `shape` you posted does not look like a diamond... How about a `solid` diamond?

Comment: Maybe this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548099/printing-simple-diamond-pattern-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as an horizontal mirror of a string with a "-" at positions going from last to first and back to last:

```
side = 6
for position in range(1-side,side): # last to first, and back (abs value)
    A = [" "]*side                  # left half
    A[abs(position)] = "-"          # set "-" at position
    A += A[-2::-1]                  # mirror for right side
    print(*A)

    
          -          
        -   -        
      -       -      
    -           -    
  -               -  
-                   -
  -               -  
    -           -    
      -       -      
        -   -        
          -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Face:

    fc = 0
    facesize = 0
    radius= 0

    def __init__(self, fc):
        self.fc = fc
        self.facesize = self.fc+1
        self.radius= int(self.facesize/2)

    def shift(self, spaces):
        leftshift= ""
        for shift in range(spaces):
            leftshift= leftshift + " " #+ str(shift)
        return leftshift



    
    def printface(self):
        radius = self.radius
        eyeLine = int(self.facesize*.3)
        noseLine = eyeLine +1
        mouthLine = int(self.facesize*.7)

        for line in range(self.facesize):
            
            if (line > radius):
                s = line - radius
            else:
                s = radius - line

            leftshift= self.shift(s)
        
            l=0
            if (s != radius):
            
                if (line > radius):
                    l = (line - (2*radius))*-2
                else:
                    l = (line *2)
                    
                

            rightshift = self.shift(l)

            if (l==0 or l==(self.facesize)):
                print(line, leftshift, " -")
            else:
                print(line,leftshift, "-", rightshift, "-")


face = Face(10)

face.printface()
```