# How do you make a inverted print-out of a shape?

Tags: python, loops

I am creating a drawing of a 90-degree triangle out of stars for an assignment in my coding camp. It looks like this:

```
lines = int(input("How many lines of stars do you want?"))

for i in range (lines):
 for j in range(i+1):
  print("*",end="")
print()
```

I want to pretty much flip it by the side and turn it into something like this:

[image: The flipped version]

I also sooner or later want to turn it into a diamond, something like this:

[image: The diamond]

I need help with how I should change the code to make it into these drawings. I tried changing the code around myself but it didn't work, and  I honestly didn't know what to change in the code.

I tried changing it by:

```
lines = int(input("How many lines of stars do you want?"))

for i in range (lines):
 for j in range(i+1):
  print("",end="*")
print()
```

But it didn't do anything

Besides that, I had no idea what to do, as I said above.

Comment: Please show your code as-text, not images, and all your attempts to change the code. Refer [help] on asking good questions.

Comment: Also how to print the diamond pattern [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548099/printing-simple-diamond-pattern-in-python)

Comment: hint: print spaces at the beginning of the line, instead of stars. You know the total width of the drawing, so you should be able to figure out how many spaces to print before stars, right?

Comment: Check https://pynative.com/print-pattern-python-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to print a reversed right trianlge:

```
n=5
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(" "*(n-i),end='')
        
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print("*",end='')
    print()
```

Output:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```